# iOS How to differentiate a UIWebView's request?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsurlcache, nsurlprotocol

How to differentiate a NSURLRequest between UIWebView and NSURLConnection in NSURLProtocol or NSURLCache?

I want to monitor a UIWebView's request without NSURLConnection, how to do?

The UIWebView's content has resource: `js`, `image`, `href`.

How to differentiate the NSURLRequest from this resource and common NSURLConnection?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

look at the url you get from the request that is passed to the delegates

```
NSURL *urlRequest = ((NSHTTPURLRequest*)request).URL;
```

if you are inside a NSURLConnectionDelegate, this will get the request. If you are not, forget this line ;)

```
NSURLRequest *request = connection.originalRequest;
```

Comment: Sorry, I want to in the NSURLProtocol's method + (BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request, judge the request whether is from a UIWebView or NSURLConnection.